# Forward domain as a parameter to a masked new domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm setting up a domaineering website and I'd like to forward domains that I have for sale to a "catch-all" type main domain that has contact info etc, but I'd like people to only see the url of the domain that's for sale. My main site has a url structure like `example.com/domain/_domain_` where `_domain_` is the actual domain name that's for sale.

For example, going to

```
example-for-sale.com
```

will show the content from

```
example-main.com/domain/example-for-sale
```

but the visitor will only see the original domain in the address bar

```
example-for-sale.com
```

More complexly, there's many `example-for-sale` domains, so a dynamic approach would be prefered to writing a redirect for each domain I have for sale.

Right now I redirect users using PHP, but this doesn't mask the domain name at all:

```
$domain_this = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; // I also strip .com/.net/etc from here
$domain_that = "http://example-main.com/domain/";

header( 'Location: '. $domain_that . $domain_this );
```

I've looked into .htaccess mod_rewrite but I haven't found a way to send the original domain as a parameter to the new one, all while keeping the new one masked.

Is this even possible? I'm fine using PHP, .htaccess, or something similar that I'm forgetting. I'd like to avoid using frames since they tend to not look professional.

Answer (score 1):

From the information given you could achieve this by:

```
// Do your TLD stripping, whatever you're doing now likely works fine.
$domain_this = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

// Get the path to the file you're wanting to show the user. Keep security in mind here.
$page = __DIR__ . '/domain/' . $domain_this;

// Don't redirect, just include the contact page
include $page;
```

Mind you this is making the assumption that the pages are hosted on the same box as those domains for sell. I would have asked for more details but I don't have the reputation to comment yet.

Comment: Sadly, the domains aren't on the same account. An oversight on my part when I got things set up. Long term I'll transfer them all on the same server, but they aren't at the moment so this wont work for now.